# A limit with an arctan

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I need to calculate another limit, $$ \underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan x\right)^{\sin\left(2/x\right)}$$

I have no idea how to start or what to do because I've never dealt with an arctan in a limit before.

What should I do first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \tan x = \infty$, so $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, as $\tan x$ and $\arctan x$ are inverse functions of each other for $x \in [0, \pi/2)$.

The rest is just direct substitution. You should get:

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^{\sin(0)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} 1^0 = \boxed{1}.$$

Comment: I fixed the exponent, but I'd also remove the second $\lim_{x\to\infty}$,

Comment: Alright, I'll delete that part. I thought there would be a way to conclude directly from $\sin(0) = 0$, which would leave open the possibility of having a limit with $0^0$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: don't panic! :-)

There is a nice identity for the arctangent:
$$
\arctan x+\arctan\frac{1}{x}=
\begin{cases} \pi/2 & x>0 \\[4px] -\pi/2 & x<0 \end{cases}
$$
Since the limit is for $x\to\infty$, it's not restrictive to assume $x>0$, so
$$
\arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\frac{1}{x}
$$
and, setting $y=1/x$, the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{y\to0^+}\Bigl(1-\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan y\Bigr)^{\sin2y}
$$
which is not an indeterminate form because it is $1^0=1$.